# What is an Ants Letter™?

Tags: knowledge, anagram, letters

*<sub>This is a variant on the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463).</sub>*

---

If a *letter* conforms to a special rule, I call it an Ants Letter™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Ants™ | Not-Ants™ |
| --- | --- |
| K | B |
| T | G |
| U | O |
| A | R |
| P | I |

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each letter can be tested for whether it is an Ants Letter™ without relying on the other letters.

These **are** (currently) the only examples of Ants Letters™!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An Ants Letter is one which:

> begins the name of a country of the world which ends in '**STAN**' (an anagram of 'ANTS').

Like so:

> K = Kazakh**stan**, Kyrgyz**stan**;
>  T = Tajiki**stan**, Turkmeni**stan**;
>  U = Uzbeki**stan**;
>  A = Afghani**stan**;
>  P = Paki**stan**.
>
>  No country of the world begins with B, G, O, R or I and also ends in 'stan'.

Comment: No fricking way! 

Comment: @Smartest1here Way! :)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent you from answering .

Comment: Post after midnight UTC ;-)